# Smoke being generated blocky

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was trying to render this two smokes being generated by following particles along a path determined by a force, I already applied all transforms for both domain and emitters and it still renders like this.
The last thing I tried, before posting, was to change density in hopes it was going to become more soft but it stills renders like its.
The smoke is emitted from a cube and I dont know if this changed anything but right know I just truly dont know how to fix this blocky look.
[image: Render of the smoke in Cycles]

Also, here is the blend file, I cleared the scene and just left the particles there.
[image]

Comment: Domain resolution is really low. In this scenario you can try to use two domains - back one with lower resolution front (close to camera) with higher res. Minimase domain size as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem regularly and i figured out this is because of low **Resolution** , you need to increase **Resolution Divisions** of your domain to something like 400 or 500 for good results but **WARNING** if you are working on a low spec device like a normal consumer laptop , Even with 4 gb or 8bg ram this could be problematic but if you have a good build with some OKAY graphics , 500 divisions should not be a problem but on a simple laptop Blender will HANG as hell of you even crank up to 200